# Estimating Azure costs for an asp.net website & Db?

Tags: azure, hosting, azure-sql-database

I have recently been looking at Azure as a hosting platform for a number of small asp.net websites with MSSql database back-ends. I currently use a non-microsoft host that charges a fixed amount each month.

The Azure demos and webinars that I have seen are very seductive. 
The problem I have is that I need some predictability on costs so that I can charge my clients appropriately. I've run thru a number of pricing calculators but have gotten a wide mix of results. In the real world what could I expect?

The sites would be low traffic (<100 unique visits a day).

My biggest fear is that I would open the management dashboard some day and see a bill that is far bigger then what I quoted a client.

Anyone have experience with Azure, and could give me some insight into their experiences?

As an example: I currently have 6 small sites that I have under my reseller account at a hosting service. I pay ~$35.00/month for all the space I need, including SQL, and bandwidth.

Comment: Hmm... As i know if you use SQL on Azure, it will costly. But, if you only host static IP, Azure is good option. Why not take a look at other hosting provider? How many SQL do you need?

Comment: It's not that costly. You can get a 1gb SQL Azure database for $10 a month. You can get a Azure Website for about $15 a month. Bandwidth would be negligible, a couple of cents a month. Sure it costs more than cheapo internet hosting, but you get a lot more as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me share my thoughts on this.

Before looking at costs, I think **`what you need to evaluate if a cloud platform is a right platform for your applications`**. The picture below summarizes some of the common application patterns:

[image]

2 biggest benefits (at least to me) that you get out of any cloud platform is `elasticity` and `pay-per-use` pricing model. Generally speaking for low volume sites, cloud is generally costlier than other hosting providers. The questions you may want to ask yourself are:

- Do my applications need `elasticity` as far as resource consumption is concerned? Or in other words, will there be a scenario where you would need 1 server for a week and then 10 servers for next week and then 1 server again week after that and things like that.
- Am I willing to pay some extra even if my resources are under utilized? Or in other words, will you be happy to host a site in a single VM even if with a hosting company you can host 10 sites in a similar sized VM?
- Will there be any scenarios where I have to handle predictable/unpredictable bursting in traffic?

If the answer is `No` to any of these questions, then IMHO Windows Azure may not be a right platform for you to host your applications.

There may be some components of Windows Azure which you can use - Storage for example where you don't have to worry about running out of disk space ever or Mobile Services so that you don't have to worry about building a backend for any mobile applications you may develop.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I don't think there can be a concrete answer unless OP puts some concrete numbers for current hosting. Then we can do straight cost comparison.

Comment: Agreed it doesn't answer the question directly, (I was probably not as clear as I could have been), but it does give me some useful information and furthers my understanding of things.